# Small Nectarine plants - Leaves turn yellow

Tags: leaves, watering, nutrients, nectarines

I planted some nectarine seeds a while ago and they have been growing slow but steady for the past few months. I have 4 smaller (approx. same-size all of them) plants and I've seen that lately the leaves of two of them are turning yellow. Even with a redish tip. What could be the cause of this? I can't see any bugs or attack of any kind. These plants are placed indoors with a constant temperature or 18-20 deg C. During the previous months (winter here in France) they have received limited amount of sun.

What could be the cause? Too much water? Too little water? Nutrient deficiency?

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

from the above info and the photo I see it seems like it's a 
mobile nutrient deficiency

this is when the plant decides to "canablise/sacrifice/transport" some of the nutrients in the lower leaves to transport them to the top where high hormone levels produce increased growth towards the light.
this produces a higher demand on certain nutrients.

this is normal and expected even more so  given that you didn't fertilise since germination.

you seem to be doing a good job keeping it happy 
it's not starving but you should keep an eye on the new leaves as well.

[image]
if the top leaves grow fully and have a lighter shade of green then it would be "nitrogen deficiency"

Answer (score 0):

The leaves look deep green and healthy, maybe even a little too long for the size of the stem/stalk so maybe you have been a bit over-generous with the fertilizer, either with the initial load in the potting soil or subsequent watering. The tips changing colour looks normal, leaves make their contribution, then fall when their job is done, I don't see any reason to think there is a problem.

The peach/nectarine family is very sensitive to wet roots, so when you think the time is right to move it up to a larger pot try to ensure that you use very free-draining soil, and water well but infrequently, allowing the root ball to become fairly dry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I haven't used any fertilizer at all. I planted them in citrus-composition-compost, a bag I bought at the local plant store. I use the same compost/soil for my lemons and Avocado for example. On the other hand I water them quite often, 3 times a week maybe (small amounts), do you think that's too much? I make sure the soil is dry before though. They seem to drink like crazy!

Comment: remember that the way plant eats is that the nutrients are washed from the soil across the roots and some would inevitably leach out as the water flushes it away.